# Ajax pagination using Mustache JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

Is it possible to implement pagination when using Mustache templates?
I'm currently using templates to output results from JSON:

**JS function:**

```
$.getJSON('assets/data/results.json', function(data) {
  var template = $('#results-template').html();
  var info = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
  $('.result-list').html(info);
```

**Example Template:**

```
<script id="results-template" type="text/template">
    {{#results}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{field1}}</td>
                    <td>{{field2}}</td>
                    <td>{{field3}</td>
                </tr>

    {{/results}}
</script>
```

I can output the results fine, but don't know where to start re. pagination when using MustacheJS.

Comment: I don't believe you can implement pagination using mustache alone. You'll have to use a jquery plugin for that. Something like datatables.net would be a better fit. It'll take your markup and turn it into a nice table with pagination, filtering...etc.

Comment: Yes, I expected I might need to incorporate a jquery plugin but wanted to know if anyone had success integrating one using Mustache. I've tried a couple so far with no success.

Comment: Thanks rivarolle, have it working now using datatables so working on ajax pagination at the moment

Comment: @user2107041 would you mind sharing the solution you developed?  I am looking at a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mootools have a plugin for this purpose also that works with JSON data

http://mootools.net/forge/p/xpagination